# How to call a middleware from another middleware in Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, design-patterns, middleware

I am working on a middleware restructuring where I am not able to call a middleware from another middleware. This is to avoid messy lines of code in the router level and move them to the function or design pattern level. Below is the example of a router code:

```
router.post("/v1/user", jwt.auth(), common.checkBasicValidations, auth.checkRBACAccess([auth.access.user], [auth.operation.create, auth.operation.update], auth.checkDomainAccessFromUserEmail, ["email"]), auth.checkRBACAccess([auth.access.user], [auth.operation.create, auth.operation.update], auth.checkDomainAccessFromUserId, ["_id"]), auth.checkAuthorized(), users.postUser);
```

`jwt.auth()`, `common.checkBasicValidations`, `auth.checkAuthorized()` is repeating almost in every router. To get rid of the above code I did something like this:

```
router.get("/v1/user", policy.validatePolicies("course"), users.getLoginguserInfo);
```

`policy.validatePolicies("course")` is a function which is handling all the above functions sequentially.

```
const validatePolicies = (category) => async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // validate JWT Token
        jwt.auth();

        //fetch users info by email
        req.user = users.sessionUserInfo(req, res, next)

        // validate Payload

        //Validate RBAC Accsess
        rbac.checkRBACAccess();

        //Validate Resourse access
        resource.checkResourceAccess(category)

    } catch (err) {
        log.warn("Problem in validatePolicies: ", err);
        return next(ApiError.internal("Something went wrong")) && next(e.message);
    }
    next();
}
```

I don't know why `jwt.auth()` isn't getting call. If you have any suggestions for using a different design pattern or improving the current flow, please share them with me.

```
const auth = () => (req, res, next) => {
// varify jwt token
}

module.exports = {
  auth
}
```

Comment: `jwt.auth()` does not itself check the jwt, it *returns a middleware* that does.

Comment: "*`jwt.auth(), common.checkBasicValidations, auth.checkAuthorized()` is repeating almost in every router.*" - then just extract that line into a helper function. Not the whole thing. Notice that you can also install middlewares on a router one after the other, you don't have to put them all in a single call in a single line. See the express docs. That'll simplify your helper function a lot.

Comment: Thanks Bergi! let me go through the express docs one more time.